# How to control memory while using Keras with tensorflow backend?

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have created a wrapper class which initializes a `keras.models.Sequential` model and has a couple of methods for starting the training process and monitoring the progress. I instantiate this class in my `main` file and perform the training process. Fairly mundane stuff.

My **question** is:

How to free all the GPU memory allocated by `tensorflow`. I tried the following with no luck:

```
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as K
with K.get_session() as sess:
    K.set_session(sess)
    import tensorflow as tf
    from neural_net import NeuralNet
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        nn = NeuralNet('config', train_db_path, test_db_path)
        nn.train(1000, 1)
        print 'Done'
    K._SESSION.close()
    K.set_session(None)
```

Even after the session has been closed and reset to `None`, `nvidia-smi` does not reflect any reduction in memory usage. Any ideas?

**Idea**

Would it be meaningful to add a `__exit__` method to my `NeuralNet` class and instantiate it as:

```
with NeuralNet() as nn:
    nn.train(1000, 1)
```

How should I free up the resources of the keras model in this method?

**Test environment**

I'm using iPython Notebook on an Ubuntu 14.04 with 3 GTX 960 GPUs.

Reference:

1. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2102
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/MFUEY9P1sc8

Comment: was wondering if you found a solution to this! i cant seem to find a way to have tensorflow (via keras) release the memory without exiting the python process

Comment: Nope. Moved away from Keras. Using just tensorflow with graphs and sessions.

Comment: Did you try K.clear_session()

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me to reinitialize the state of Keras layers in my Jupyter notebook for every run:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
```

Also, the graph is named and reset every time the notebook runs using:

```
graphr = K.get_session().graph
with graphr.as_default():
    #...graph building statements...
```

Note : I am still trying to wrap my head around the concepts of Keras and tensorflow ( I believe they are described poorly in documentation and examples ) but the above works.

Comment: Does clearing a session keep all existing models and their weights?

Comment: Weights are cleared, graphs are kept, sorry for late response. Somehow I did not receive notifications...

Comment: @xor007: Correct me if I am wrong. If weights are cleared then what is the use of using `clear_session`? All the trained weights will be lost.

Comment: @SrinivasValekar, if you need to keep the weights, indeed you should not call `clear_session`.  However, when I am experimenting with hyper parameters, I sometimes want to "forget" learned weights on a graph that is in a running Jupyter notebook. In this case, `clear_session` does it.

Comment: @xor007: Thanks for the quick response, could you please tell me which will be the best way to tackle `MemoryError` for training a model? I am getting MemoryError after 1st epoch. Here is what I am doing - After the first epoch I am saving the model then using `clear_session` and loading the model and retraining it. Is this the correct way?